# Redirecting anonymous user to specific page

Tags: views, entities, users

I have a view (d7, views3) that is set up as a table with several fields and the far right column is a global custom text field containing some html like this in the text box:

```
<a href="/[title]">Enroll</a>
```

When an anonymous user comes to that page and clicks on that link, it forces them to the login page.  But then after they log in, it takes them to their main user page instead of the node that they would have gone to if they had been logged in.  Is there a way to send the user to the page they should have gone to after login ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set destination after login to which you want the user to redirect to.

So consider this example a login link like  www.sitename.com/login?destination=node/1 will take user to node/1 after login.

More detail:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_destination/7

one of you comment says you are using login redirect module, I have not used this module before the module page on drupal.org itself says it covers the functionality you are looking for.

> A simple module providing a method to redirect users according to an
>   URL-defined parameter after logging in. Allows redirects toward
>   non-Drupal location.

So the reason the that ?destination is not working, might be because of you a redirect rule triggered by login redirect module.

So solution can be set conditional redirection in login redirect module which can be checked using the parameters in url.

Comment: So where would I put that login link ??

Comment: how you are taking user to login page?

Comment: Not sure.  The system is detecting that the user is not logged in when they click on that link to go to the page with that title and brings up a login page.  Then they are taken to their main user page.

Comment: are you open for custom coding?

Comment: I am not sure if the current redirection to login page is handled by system or is there any custom code or any rule making it to behave so.Because if any of the two is the case then your solution might be just adding ?destination parameter to the redirection rule

Comment: This site has login toboggan & login redirect enabled but not any custom code that I can see.  I tried to add the destination parameter like <a href="/user?destination=[title]">Enroll</a> but it still just goes to the main user page after login.  Also have to be able to just go straight to that title page when already logged in.

Comment: Haven't been able to find a redirect rule triggered by login redirect module yet.  I don't see on the config page for the module where it lets you do any conditional redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Go to configuration -> System then clicks on Site information 
Come to the bottom of the page you will find out "FRONT PAGE"